Determining Parameter Values for Solutions of a System of Equations
I am working on a system of equations involving absolute values:
$$
\begin{cases} 
|x - 2| + y = 3 \\ 
|x + y| = m 
\end{cases}
$$
I need to determine the values of the parameter $m$ for which the system has:

A unique solution
Two solutions
No solutions

Here is what I have so far:

There is a unique solution when $ m = 0 $ or $m > 5$.
There are two solutions when $0 < m < 5 $.
There are no solutions when $ m = 5$.

Could someone help verify this reasoning or provide a detailed explanation for why these cases occur?

Did you try graphing the solutions? What does the graph look like when $m=0$? $0<m<5$? $m=5$? $m>5$?

You may want to reconsider the case when $m=5$. There should be a solution. Also, what happens when $m<0$?

Since the absolute value is nonnegative, there will be no solutions when $m<0$. Assume $m\geq 0$.
Let us draw the graph of the function $|x−2|+y=3$ (in blue).

We are now looking for intersections of this graph with the graph of the function $|x+y|=m$. Notice that we have $|x+y|=m$ iff $x+y=m$ or $x+y=-m$, so the graph of $|x+y|=m$ consists of two lines of the form $y=-x\pm m$. Thus it is clear that the graphs will intersect at

one point if $m=0$
two points if $0<m<5$
an infinite amount of points if $m=5$
one point if $m>5$.

